# Preferred way of getting module filename of dll in C++/CLI

Tags: winapi, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI dll and I'd like to know what the preferred alternative to the Win32 API function `GetModuleFilename` would be. I've found `Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->ManifestModule->FullyQualifiedName` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.manifestmodule.aspx)). This seems to be working, but I'd like to know if there's a different or "better" way. Of course, I know that technically nothing prohibits me from using `GetModuleFilename` directly, but I hate mixing different APIs and this would also require to create a string buffer which I'd then have to convert back into a `System::String`. I know it's only two more lines of code but still ... ;-)

Comment: Don't you think that if there was any more straightforward solution you would have find it by now ? ;)

Comment: I'm pretty new to the whole managed world so I don't know ;-) Sometimes I just prefer asking people with more experience instead of searching for hours by myself. Also, the integration of C++/CLI in VS2010 is not very great - for example Intellinonsense and the online help pretty much don't work at all :/

Comment: I don't see how any other solution could be better. One thing you could do is wrap this in your own function with a smaller name, but the function you are calling stays the same, you're just renaming it. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `GetModuleFileName()`, the .NET 4.0 CLR has dropped some appcompat code that makes a loaded assembly resemble a regular DLL.  Besides, the HMODULE is trouble, you cannot use the VirtualQuery trick to convert a code address to a HMODULE.

`Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->Location` gives you the full path to the assembly from which the IL for the current method was loaded.

Comment: Mixed-mode assemblies, at least, are still valid native images.  I think.  But you're right that `GetModuleFileName` won't necessarily return anything reasonable when called from managed code, since JIT-generated native functions lie outside the memory-mapped section.

Comment: Thanks, good to know that using GetModuleFilename was not safe.